# Show different entry-meta for front & single page

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, genesis

I am a non-coder, I am trying to implement different entry-meta for home & single page.

For homepage I want to keep **[post_author_posts_link]** **[post_modified_date]** **[post_edit]**

**Backend Code:**

```
//* Customize the post info function
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'explore_post' );
function explore_post($post_info) {
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    $post_info = '[post_author_posts_link] [post_modified_date] [post_edit]';
    return $post_info;
}}
```

**Result**

[Screenshots1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ppc6.png)

---

For a single page, I want the same output, but when someone hovers their mouse over **admin**, I want it to automatically show me the author box information with post link, as shown in the screenshots.

[Screenshots2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrU1m.png)

How can I make on single page? Please help me.

Thanks & Regards

Abhishek